# How can I read a upload text file in Grails that I store in my Database

Tags: grails, file-upload

I'm trying to read an uploaded file in Grails. It's a text write in word. I can upload the file and store in the db, but I only get the file in bytes with the method .getBytes and in the db I store a lot of lines of symbols, but I can't read the message that I have in write in the file.

In my method Controller

```
def save(Book bookInstance) {
...

   CommonsMultipartFile testFile = request.getFile('templateFile')
   bookInstance.letter = new String(testFile.getBytes())
...
```

My Domain

```
class Book {
   String name
   String letter        

   static mapping = {
      template type: 'text'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your file is a `CommonsMultipartFile` you can do the following to read the contents as a string:

```
CommonsMultipartFile testFile = request.getFile('templateFile')
bookInstance.letter = testFile.getFileItem().getString()
```

Take a look at the API [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.html) for more information.

Comment: Hi @JoshuaMoore. This don't work for me. I can't see the Hello World that I have in the file. I see this: PKOS¼F^Æ2''mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.textPKOS¼Fý¯>VööThumbnails/thumbnail.pngPNG  IHDRµzA ½IDATxíÛÍoåÇññfmâ7bº~I4&L!-¢ZKU¡Ú¿ ÿAø·8@{joTÁqAUC9P^b`RÝÎî"øIÞ&$>ÃÈ±¬±æëçyv·[×u~@÷~4}èD$ú Ñ>Hô....

Comment: @Salva, It's not a good idea to use a String to store a binary content. Your code should work if the uploaded file were a plain text file. But looking your error I can see you are storing an OpenOffice document, internally handled as a zip file, so a binary file. Try to use another type (byte[] array) supported by your database, or use a different method to store files, like write them in a local folder or upload them to a server (s3 or similar), and store only the uri to fetch them.